# How to draw rectangle box over an image present inside div?

Tags: javascript, html

I have developed a page where I dynamically import images and display them inside a div tag. Now i wanted to draw an rectangle over the image, and it should start from any point on the image.

I referred many sources and tried to implement the idea from it.

```
  <style>
#rubberBand {
position: absolute;
visibility: hidden;
 width: 0px; height: 0px;
 border: 2px solid red;
}
 </style>

   <div class="imageside" id="picture"> </div>
   <div ID="rubberBand"></div>
```

In the above code, the image is display at the div id "picture". Till this part of the code works fine.

```
 var pic, rubber, pt = { x: 0, y: 0 };

 picture= getpicture();

 function getpicture(){
 pic= document.getElementById('picture')
 pic.innerHTML= getgImage(event.target.dataset.number);

 }

 function startRubber (evt) {
 var ev = evt || window.event,
  rs = rubber.style,
  bb = pic.innerHTML.getBoundingClientRect();
  console.dir(ev);
  rs.left = bb.left + 'px';
  rs.top = bb.top + 'px';
  rs.width = bb.width + 'px';
  rs.height = bb.height + 'px';
  rs.display = 'block';
  pt = { x: ev.clientX - bb.left, y: ev.clientY - bb.top };
  return false;
  }

  function stopRubber () {
  rubber.style.display = 'none';
  }

  function moveRubber (evt) {
  var ev = evt || window.event;
  rubber.style.left = (evt.clientX - pt.x) + 'px';
  rubber.style.top = (evt.clientY - pt.y) + 'px';
  }

  rubber = document.getElementById('rubberBand');

  pic = document.getElementById('picture').innerHTML;

  pic.onmousedown = startRubber;
  document.onmouseup = stopRubber;
  document.onmousemove = moveRubber;
```

In the above code, the function getpicture() is responsible to display the images dynamically. When i execute the above code, the image displays on the page, but I am not able to draw the rectangle over the image. In console, no errors. Can someone help me out with problem and help me to draw the rectangle over the image.

Answer (score 0):

check this out.

https://jsfiddle.net/2at9n7ye/3/

your issue is that you are accessing the pic variable before you load it.

```
var pic, rubber, pt = {
  x: 0,
  y: 0
};

picture = getpicture();

function getpicture() {
  pic = document.getElementById('picture');
  pic.innerHTML = "<img src='https://i.imgur.com/mvMlmMb.jpg' id='img' width='100px' height='100px'/>";

}

function startRubber(evt) {
  var ev = evt || window.event,
    rs = rubber.style,
    bb = pic.getBoundingClientRect
  rs.left = bb.left + 'px';
  rs.top = bb.top + 'px';
  rs.width = bb.width + 'px';
  rs.height = bb.height + 'px';
  rs.display = 'block';
  pt = {
    x: ev.clientX - bb.left,
    y: ev.clientY - bb.top
  };
  return false;
}

function stopRubber() {
  rubber.style.display = 'none';
}

function moveRubber(evt) {
  var ev = evt || window.event;
  rubber.style.left = (evt.clientX - pt.x) + 'px';
  rubber.style.top = (evt.clientY - pt.y) + 'px';
}

(function() {
  rubber = document.getElementById('rubberBand');
  pic = document.getElementById('picture');
  pic.addEventListener("mousedown", startRubber);
  document.addEventListener("mouseup", stopRubber);
  document.addEventListener("mousemove", moveRubber);
})();
```